# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: grpc-default-executor-0 PID: 10113

Tags: java, android, flutter, assertion

** I did updated My gradle version in flutter android but  3.3.0 to 4.0.1 and run my app that time occure above and below error any one tell me how can i solve this error.....I did clean and rebuild apk................................................**

Logcat:

```
10-14 04:26:41.344 10861-10928/com.muhammadali.riaz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: grpc-default-executor-0
    Process: com.muhammadali.riaz, PID: 10861
    java.lang.AssertionError
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.getResourceResolver(DnsNameResolver.java:536)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.access$500(DnsNameResolver.java:60)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$1.run(DnsNameResolver.java:211)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: are you android clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes I did clean and rebuild but did not solved yet

Comment: Are you able to solve this?

Comment: Are you able to solve this?